# Expected value of visits state in finite markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I have 4 states {human, dog, cat, floor). Flea can move between each state (always with same probability). In state human flea is dying (end game), in state {cat, dog} flea eats, and on floor flea is starving. Count expected values of meals{dog, cat}, starting from floor and before dying in human.

This is my transition matrix (3 states - Hungry, Meal, Dead)
$$ A = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\ \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right) $$

I think about counting expected values of visit of state Meal (starting from Hungry and before die in Dead), but I don't have any idea, how to start

Comment: I don't get it. Number of steps could count Hungry state as well

Comment: starting from floor, flea has prob(2/3) to eat and 1/3 to die

Comment: from my calculation T is equal to 3 so 2/3(3-1) is equal to 4/3, but the answer in book is 4.

Comment: so maybe my matrix is wrong?

Comment: i was wandering the same, but i assumed that is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is either $1.5$ or $2$, depending on the interpretation of the problem.

Let $e_f$ be the expected number of future meals if the flea is currently on the floor, $e_c$ the number of future meals if the flea is on the cat, and $e_d$ the number of future meals if it is on the dog.  Clearly $e_c=e_d$.

Under the assumption that the flea always changes state, we have $$\begin{align}
e_f&=\frac23(e_c+1)\\
e_c&=\frac13e_f+\frac13(e_d+1)
\end{align}$$
Solving we get $e_c=\frac54,\ e_f=\frac32$.

Under the assumption that the flea may stay in the same state, we have $$\begin{align}
e_f&=\frac14e_f+\frac12(e_c+1)\\
e_c&=\frac14+\frac12(e_c+1)
\end{align}$$
and we get $e_c=e_f=2$

I've done two simulations, one for each case  In the first case, and the results agree with these.  In an earlier version of this post, I said that the simulation in the first case gave $1.7$, but there must have been some error in the code.  I've rewritten it, and it gives $1.5$.

Here's my python script for the first simulation:

```
from random import random

floor, cat, dog, human = range(4)

def test(trials):
    meals  = 0
    for _ in range(trials):
        state = floor
        while state != human:
            r = random()
            if state == floor:
                if r <= 1/3:
                    state = cat
                elif r <= 2/3:
                    state = dog
                else:
                    state = human
            elif state == cat:
                if r <= 1/3:
                    state = floor
                elif r <= 2/3:
                    state = dog
                else:
                    state = human
            elif state == dog:
                if r <= 1/3:
                    state = floor
                elif r <=2/3:
                    state = cat
                else:
                    state = human
            if state in (cat,dog):
                meals += 1
    return meals/trials
```

Here's my python script for the second case:

```
from random import random

floor, cat, dog, human = range(4)

def test(trials):
    meals  = 0
    for _ in range(trials):
        state = floor
        while state != human:
            r = random()
            if state == floor:
                if r <= 1/4:
                    state = cat
                elif r <= 1/2:
                    state = dog
                elif r <= 3/4:
                    state = floor
                else:
                    state = human
            elif state == cat:
                if r <= 1/4:
                    state = floor
                elif r <= 1/2:
                    state = dog
                elif r <= 3/4:
                    state = cat
                else:
                    state = human
            elif state == dog:
                if r <= 1/4:
                    state = floor
                elif r <=1/2:
                    state = cat
                elif r <= 3/4:
                    state = dog
                else:
                    state = human
            if state in (cat,dog):
                meals += 1
    return meals/trials
```

Surely we should be able to state this in term of the transition matrix.

**EDIT**

I haven't had a chance to read it yet, but section 9.2 of [these lecture notes](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/absorption_and_reward_color.pdf) addresses the question.

Comment: I have the same result in both cases, but this exercise has a second subtask(?), calculate the probability that flea dies hungry(without eating meal) and the answer in the book is 1/3. So i think that flea should always change state

Comment: @cvzx Yes, that would make sense.

Comment: OK I found an answer on the internet that expected values of number of steps flea makes before death is 3, so the number of meals should be less than 3.  So the answer in the book is not correct.

Comment: If you look at the lecture notes I referred to at the end, you'll find that the answers you get by using its formula agree with the answers I've computed here.

Comment: Yeah, i got 3/2 as well